# What is the name of the tmux server / daemon?

Tags: tmux

Is it true that there is tmux daemon or server running on a Unix / Linux system?  If so, what is its name and how can we use

```
ps ax | grep -i <the_name>
```

to be able to see it running?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ps | grep`. Use `pgrep`. And if you're using Linux (where both `pgrep` and `ps` are buggy), use grep directly: `grep -H . $(grep -li tmux /proc/[0-9]*/comm)`

Comment: interesting it has to be `pgrep -l tmux` for it to work. Without the `-l` it won't show the name

Comment: That's not very interesting. It's the documented behaviour. `pgrep -a tmux` will show even more info. Both the process name (`comm`) and the arguments (`cmdline`) can be faked by a process. If you want to find all the processes which are running a binary, use `lsof`. Or `grep -H '.*' $(find /proc/[0-9]*/exe -lname /usr/bin/tmux 2>/dev/null -printf '%h/comm\n')`

Comment: that's interesting from the perspective of somebody not familiar with `pgrep`. Should there be only one perspective in the world? I am wondering why `ps ax | grep tmux` won't be able to show it, and if I do `pgrep -l tmux` it showed 14975 for the tmux server, and if I do `ps 14975` it showed the process for `tmux new`, not the server

Comment: `ps | grep` won't show it because the tmux server changes it's _process name_ to `tmux: server` (`/proc/PID/comm`) NOT its _command line arguments_ (`/proc/PID/cmdline`) which ps is showing by default. Also, if you read the manpages and test the commands, you will change your perspective to someone's familiar with them ;-)

Comment: Sometimes `pgrep` will not find the command due to its name having been changed.  For example, on my Mint system, `pgrep firefox` returns nothing, whereas `pgrep -f firefox` (more or less equivalent to `ps -ef | grep firefox`) finds all the firefox PIDs.  So, depending on the specific command and system, you may have to use  `pgrep`, `pgrep -f` (or `ps -ef | grep`), or some more complicated command such as @mosvy suggests above.

Comment: Is this not a valid Unix / Linux question for it to deserve a "-1" vote?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `tmux` session running (attached or detached), then yes, there’s a `tmux` server running, and you can see it by looking for a `tmux` process with no tty. Its “comm” entry will be changed to “tmux: server”:

```
 $ ps -t- | grep tmux
 2109406 ?        00:00:00 tmux: server
```

or

```
 $ pgrep -l tmux
 2109406 tmux: server
```

Comment: interesting... this is the first time I see a `ps -t-`... it works well on Ubuntu but not on macOS