# What are the differences between pgrep and `ps aux | grep`?

Tags: grep, ps, pgrep

Why is `pgrep` needed? If we can use `ps` and `grep` together, why do we need `pgrep`? It'd be weird if we have a command `lsgrep` or `curlgrep`.

But one difference I noticed was, if we first start a tmux session with

```
tmux new -s foo
```

then

```
ps aux | grep tmux
```

won't be able to find the tmux server process, but

```
pgrep -l tmux
```

can.  But still, why don't we have a flag with `ps` so that we can `grep` like `pgrep` does to be able to see the tmux server process? What are the differences between `ps` with `grep` and `pgrep`?

Comment: I've already told you [why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578736/what-is-the-name-of-the-tmux-server-daemon#comment1077056_578736) `ps aux | grep` won't find your process. You have to adjust `ps`'s output format with `-o ....comm,...` if you want it to show the process name.

Comment: And no, you can't use `ps | grep` together because the output format of ps is NOT standardized. In addition to the fact that the grep may find _itself_. It's the same thing as with `ls | grep`: you don't use `ls | grep`, you use `find` (call it `lsgrep` if you want).

Comment: how can you make `ps -o` show the tmux server? How about `curlgrep`? In a way `ls` is more like showing directory content and `find` is to find something deep down (and report the exact path)...

Comment: `ps -eo pid,comm | grep 'tmux.*server'`

Comment: thank you!  I found `ps -e | grep tmux` works well too

Answer (score 2):

The `ps` command has two fields that, generally, one searches in this way, the `args` and the `comm`.  The first is the program argument string, NUL-delimited.  The second is a "name" for the program.  These are stored separately, and (on various operating systems)  can *both* be altered by the program itself, at runtime.  Programs such as `tmux` do indeed do that.

The output of `ps` is *not machine parseable*.  Several fields can contain *unencoded whitespace* which makes it impossible to determine field boundaries reliably, because arbitrary length whitespace is *also* the field separator.  `args` and `comm` are indeed two such fields.  The output of `ps` is only human readable.

When you `grep` the output of `ps` you therefore are pattern matching entire lines, with no reliable way to anchor that pattern to the specific field concerned, *except* by eliminating pretty much everything else that is of any use, and that you might be trying to find by this method in the first place.

For examples:

- With your `u` option to Linux `ps` (which is `-u` in BSD `ps`), there's a `user` field that contains user names, which `grep` patterns looking for program names will also happen to match on occasion.
- The canonical problem (exemplified at "[What is the difference between ps -ef | grep WDA and ps -ef | grep [W]DA?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/377296/5132)", "[Matching for program names, why so many hits?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/417043/5132)", "[Function of second grep in `ps | grep -v | grep`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/295363/5132)", and *many* other places elsewhere) is of course that the pattern passed to `grep` matches the `grep` process's own `args`.
- It can happen to match environment strings as well, which is particularly poignant given what can often be found in a `_` environment variable.

```
% ps -a -x -e -o sid,comm,args |
  grep dbus-daemon |
  head -n 4
   25 nosh                cyclog dbus-daemon/ (nosh)
   25 dbus-daemon         dbus-daemon --config-file ./system-wide.conf --nofork --address=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
  989 dbus-daemon         dbus-daemon --config-file ./per-user.conf --nofork --address=unix:path=/run/user/JdeBP/bus
15107 grep                grep dbus-daemon
% 
% clearenv --keep-path \
  setenv WIBBLE tmux \
  ps -a -x -e -o sid,comm,command |
  grep tmux
15107 ps                  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin WIBBLE=tmux ps -a -x -e -o sid,pid,comm,command
%
```

Put another way: `grep` is for operating upon text files comprising lines.  The process table is not a text file, and treating it as if it were a text file (by translating it with the `ps` command) loses information about fields.

The way to perform such a search is to look at the process table with something other than `ps`.  On Linux, one can look directly at `/proc/${PID}/comm` and the similar psuedo-files for the argument strings, environment strings, and so forth.

Or one can write a tool that fishes out *the specific data to be matched* from the process table, and that runs pattern maching on just that field alone.  This tool is not for text files, but is for process tables.  One can call it `pgrep`.

Of course, on the gripping hand one could write a `ps` whose output one *can* process with (say) `awk`, because it *is* machine readable, encoding whitespace with `vis()` and thus providing fields that `awk` can properly recognize.  The downside is that then it is less *human*-readable and not quite what a conformant `ps` is supposed to be.  I pass its output through `console-flat-table-viewer` to read it.  ☺

```
% system-control ps -p 740 -o sid,comm,args
SID COMMAND COMMAND
25  dbus-daemon dbus-daemon\040--config-file\040./system-wide.conf\040--nofork\040'--address=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket'
% 
% system-control ps -A -o sid,comm,args,envs,tree |
  awk '{ if ("dbus-daemon"==$2) print $3; }'
dbus-daemon\040--config-file\040./system-wide.conf\040--nofork\040'--address=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket'
dbus-daemon\040--config-file\040./per-user.conf\040--nofork\040'--address=unix:path=/run/user/JdeBP/bus'
/usr/local/bin/dbus-daemon\040--fork\040--print-pid\0405\040--print-address\0407\040--session
% 
% system-control ps -A -o sid,comm,args,envs,tree |
  awk '{ if ("dbus-daemon"==$2) print $3; }' |
  unvis
dbus-daemon --config-file ./system-wide.conf --nofork '--address=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket'
dbus-daemon --config-file ./per-user.conf --nofork '--address=unix:path=/run/user/JdeBP/bus'
/usr/local/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
%
```

## Further reading

- [`ps`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ps). *NetBSD General Commands Manual*. 2016-12-02.
- [`vis`](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?vis+3). *NetBSD Library Functions Manual*. 2017-04-22.
- Shlomi Noach
  (2009-10-01).  [*How NOT to test that mysqld is alive*](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/how-not-to-test-that-mysqld-is-alive).  code.openark.org.
- Greg Wooledge.  ["The risk of parsing the process tree"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#The_risk_of_parsing_the_process_tree). *Process Management*.  Greg's Wiki.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [`clearenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/clearenv.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [`setenv`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/setenv.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). [`ps`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/ps.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2020). [`list-process-table`](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/list-process-table.xml). *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: There are no `system-control` and `clearenv` commands on any of my systems, what are those? Of course the argv+envp block is simple memory that the process can write to (I can run a program like `int main(int ac, char **av){ memcpy(av[0], "FOO=bar", 8); putenv(av[0]); pause(); }` and have `ps` show its "environment"), but it needs more explanation why this is poignant and how it could happen with regular programs.

Comment: It's not that that is poignant.  There's an explanation that `tmux` is one such program in the first paragraph.  And you need to read the further reading, although I didn't originally put the manual page for `clearenv` there as it is fairly tangential.