# On Linux, how do I determine the number of processes with the exact string "test test 123" anywhere in the process title?

Tags: terminal, process, window-title

I've already figured this out on Windows, but how to do it on Linux eludes me:

```
tasklist /V /NH | find "test test 123"
```

And then I count the number of non-empty lines in the output. This is super slow but works. Now I'm looking for the Linux method of doing the same.

That is, "test test 123" can be the full process title, it can begin with it, it can end with it, or just have it in the middle. This is important.

Comment: Use the unix commands `ps` and `grep` in place of `tasklist` and `find`. You'll have to use the appropriate command line arguments as well.

Comment: To count lines, make a final pipe to `wc -l`

Comment: Windows have titles.  Processes have accounting names and argument strings.  You should decide which you are actually scanning.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: use `pgrep -cf "test test 123"`

---

The `ps` program will list all running processes. Specifically, try:

```
ps aux
```

Now, you could just filter that list using `grep` to search for your string:

```
ps aux | grep "test test 123"
```

That will print out matching lines. To count them, use `grep -c` which prints out the number of matching lines instead:

```
ps aux | grep -c "test test 123"
```

The problem with this approach is that the `grep` process above will also appear in the results. For example, I am currently editing a file named `test test 123`, but if I run the command above, I'll see both the process of my file editor and the `grep` itself:

```
$ ps aux | grep  "test test 123"
terdon   2461453 22.0  0.2 392944 79796 pts/1    Sl   15:53   0:02 emacs test test 123
terdon   2462354  0.0  0.0   8832  2292 pts/1    S+   15:53   0:00 grep --color test test 123
```

Therefore, the `grep -c` will return `2` instead of `1`:

```
$ ps aux | grep -c "test test 123"
2
```

Which brings us to the right tool for the job, `pgrep`. This is a tool specifically designed to find processes:

```
$ pgrep -cf "test test 123"
1
```

The `-c` means "count the matches" and the `-f` means "search the entire command line, not just the process name".

The other common trick to skip the `grep` itself is to use a one-character character class instead of the same string so that the `grep` command line won't contain the string:

```
$ ps aux | grep  "test test 123"
terdon   2461453  1.2  0.2 392944 79796 pts/1    Sl   15:53   0:02 emacs test test 123
terdon   2476971  0.0  0.0   8832  2236 pts/1    S+   15:56   0:00 grep --color test test 123
$ ps aux | grep  "[t]est test 123"
terdon   2461453  1.2  0.2 392944 79796 pts/1    Sl   15:53   0:02 emacs test test 123
$ ps aux | grep -c "[t]est test 123"
1
```

For more on this trick see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186/22222). But this really isn't necessary if your system has `pgrep` as Linux systems do.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $(( $(ps aux | grep "test test 123" | wc -l) - 1))
```

should to the trick

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578816/5132 and its further reading for the reasons that it won't.